# 1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null"

Tags: python, django, archivo, csv

Tengo un código que inserta varios datos a la vez cargados de un CSV, el archivo tiene los siguientes datos:

```
("username, firstname, last_name, email, password")
```

Cuando subo el archivo obtengo este error:

```
1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null"
```

El campo id es autocomplete. Esta es mi vista:

```
def addbulkuser(request):
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the file should be: Username, First name, Last name, Email & Password'
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'andon/user_form_bulk.html', prompt)

    data_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not data_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

    data_set = data_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
        _, created = User.objects.update_or_create(
            username=column[0],
            first_name=column[1],
            last_name=column[2],
            email=column[3],
            password=column[4]
        )
        user = authenticate(username=column[0], password=column[4])
        andon_user_group = Group.objects.get(name='andon_user')
        andon_user_group.user_set.add(user)
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'andon/user_form_bulk.html', context)
```

Comment: Qué valor tienes en username=column[0],?

Comment: Un nombre, por ejemplo este: "saulss".